# WPF TreeView sub-items not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am trying to build a `TreeView` by creating and adding my `TreeViewItems` in code. I have an object of `Folders` that that contain a list of sub-folders and a list of `Sessions`. All of this is kept inside a `Root` folder object. When I use recursion to create the `TreeViewItems` and add them to my `TreeView`, the `Folders` and `Sessions` in the root folder appear but none of the `TreViewItems` that belong to their collection are displayed.

When I write out the xaml for the page by hand it displays as desired but not when added with code. I have looked at the `TreeView` object in the debugger, I can see the second and third layer of `TreeViewItems` in the `Items` collection but none of them display.

My objects

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Session
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Protocol ConnectionProtocol { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
    }

[Serializable]
    public class Folder
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int ParentID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Folder> SubFolders { get; set; } = new List<Folder>();
        public virtual List<Session> Sessions { get; set; } = new List<Session>();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Root : Folder
    {
        public KeyValuePair<ulong, int> Version
        {
            get
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<ulong, int>(_revisionNumber, GetHashCode());
            }
        }
        private ulong _revisionNumber = 0;

        public override int Id { get => 0; set { } }
        public override int ParentID { get => 0; set {  } }

        private void UpdateVersion()...

        public bool AddSession(Session session)...

        public bool RemoveSession(Session session)...

        public bool AddFolder(Folder folder)...

        public bool RemoveFolder(Folder folder)...
    }
```

And in the MainWindow

```
        private static Root root { get; set; }

        private void RefreshTree()
        {
            SessionsTree.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var sub in root.SubFolders)
                SessionsTree.Items.Add(GetNodesFromFolder(sub));

            foreach (var session in root.Sessions)
                SessionsTree.Items.Add(BuildTreeViewItem(session));

            SessionsTree.UpdateLayout();
        }

        private TreeViewItem GetNodesFromFolder(Folder folder)
        {
            TreeViewItem viewItem = BuildTreeViewItem(folder);
            foreach (var sub in folder.SubFolders)
                viewItem.Items.Add(GetNodesFromFolder(sub));

            foreach (var session in folder.Sessions)
                viewItem.Items.Add(BuildTreeViewItem(session));

            return viewItem;
        }

        private TreeViewItem BuildTreeViewItem(Folder folder)
        {
            TreeViewItem viewItem = new TreeViewItem();
            viewItem.Tag = folder;
            viewItem.Height = 14;

            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = FolderImage;
            image.Height = 14;

            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = folder.Name;

            StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
            stackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(image);
            stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);

            viewItem.Header = stackPanel;

            return viewItem;
        }

        private object BuildTreeViewItem(Session session)
        {
            TreeViewItem viewItem = new TreeViewItem();
            viewItem.Tag = session;

            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = SwitchBlue;
            image.Height = 14;

            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = session.Name;
            textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(4, 0, 0, 0);

            StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
            stackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(image);
            stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);

            viewItem.Header = stackPanel;

            return viewItem;
        }
```

I would expect a tree to display such as....

```
v {} Folder 1
  v {} SubFolder 1
      [] Session
      [] Session
  > {} SubFolder 2
      [] Session
  > {} SubFolder 3
> {} Folder 2
> {} Folder 3
  [] Session
  [] Session
  [] Session
```

But what I get is

```
v {} Folder 1
v {} Folder 2
v {} Folder 3
  [] Session
  [] Session
  [] Session
```

Comment: If you are using WPF then why are you creating the control in code behind? The control should be created as XAML. Your approach of building TreeView is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When items don't contain at least one child item, then the `TreeView` or the actual node won't be expandable. If you need to add child items to the tree at a later time (e.g. lazy loading) you need to add a dummy item to make the `TreeView` to show the expander. Since you are using a `List` as child collection, you would have to create the complete tree data structure first and add it at once to the `TreeView.ItemSource` or simply use an `ObservableCollection`.

To keep things simple all node types should be stored in one shared collection which requires a common base type. Then you can simply use a `DataTemplateSelector` to create the corresponding `TreeViewItem` dynamically.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource DataTemplateSelector}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
      <local:DataTemplateSelector x:Key="DataTemplateSelector" />

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FolderDataTemplate"
                                DataType="Folder" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate x:Key="SessionDataTemplate" 
                    DataType="Session">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
  </TreeView>
</Window>
```

**DataTemplateSelector.cs**

```
class DataTemplateSelector : System.Windows.Controls.DataTemplateSelector
{
  public override DataTemplate
    SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

     return item is Session 
       ? element.FindResource("SessionDataTemplate") as DataTemplate 
       : element.FindResource("FolderDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
  }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Folders = new ObservableCollection<Folder>
    {
      new Folder("Folder_1")
      {
        ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
        {
          new Folder("Folder_1.1")
          {
            ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
            {
              new Folder("Folder_1.1.1")
              {
                ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
                {
                  new Session("SessionA"),
                  new Session("SeesionB")
                }
              },
              new Session("SessionA"),
              new Session("SeesionB")
            }
          },
          new Folder("Folder_1.2")
          {
            ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>
            {
              new Session("SessionA"),
              new Session("SeesionB")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Data item hierarchy

```
public abstract class TreeItem
{
  public TreeItem(String name)
  {
    this.Name = name;
  }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Folder : TreeItem
{
  public Folder(string name) : base(name)
  {
  }
  public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> ChildItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>();
}

public class Session : TreeItem
{
  public Session(string name) : base(name)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: This has been very helpful in getting me going in the direction of using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` but I am still struggling around the view model. I should have been more clear about the folder hierarchy and sessions being user defined. I cannot pre-load the tree because I don't have a set folder structure but lazy loading is not required. Should I be re-creating the entire `TreeView` every time an item is added or removed?

Comment: No, you don't need to rebuild the whole tree again. Just replace the `List` with an `ObservableCollection` to let the `TreeView` automatically update itself when the data structure was modified (items are added or removed or moved).

Comment: I did more looking into `HierarchicalDataTemplate' and the shared inheritance and ViewModel were what I was missing. Thank you for your help!